# How to query Knowledge Articles unauthenticated using the Knowledge API

Tags: api, knowledge

According to Salesforce [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/resources_knowledge_support.htm) using the **Knowledge API** we can "allow both authorized and guest users to retrieve the user’s visible data categories and their associated articles.", however I've been unsuccessful in doing so.

I've tried making a GET request to `https://mydomain--dev.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/support/knowledgeArticles` as detailed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/resources_knowledge_support_artlist.htm) but this returns a 401 error.

Comment: shoulnt' it be guest site url or community site url instead of your internal my domain?

`https://guestSite.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/support/knowledgeArticles`

Comment: Can you formulate this into an answer. This is why I needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internal Users if they want to access rest endpoint then the endpoint would be

`https://mydomain.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/support/knowledgeArticles`

Whereas if it's for community or guest force.com site, it would be different, as MYDOMAIN is always authenticated. That explains [401 error code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401).

`https://guestSite.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/support/knowledgeArticles`